# Problema para descargar archivos php me sale CERO BYTES

Tags: php

estoy intentando hacer la descarga de archivos. Me reconoce los nombres del fichero todo. Pero al descargar lo hace en CERO BYTES. A ver si alguien ve algo irregular. Gracias!

El Archivo se encuentre dentro del directorio /files/ en el sitio.

```
<?php
Application::Uses('com.web.WebPage');

class download extends TVisualComponent{

    public $package='app.admin.ajax';
    public $respuesta=array();

    public function run(){

        $dir_subida = Application::getPath('files');
        $file = "..".$dir_subida."/".$_GET['file'];

        $file_name=explode("track_",$file);

        header("Content-type: octet/stream");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name[1].";");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));

        ob_clean();
        flush();

        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Falta el `ob_start`

Comment: Hola, perdón donde es que iria? me ayudas con el código? lo he probado todo.

Comment: echa un vistazo a esto https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/control-de-salida-php.html

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias! pero no funciona. Sigue descargando cero bytes. ves algo mas que pueda estar mal?

Comment: Quizas no te haga falta hacer el ob_clean ni el flush. http://php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir_subida = Application::getPath('files');
$file = "..".$dir_subida."/".$_GET['file'];
$file_name=explode("track_",$file);

if (file_exists($file_name[1])) {
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$file_name[1]);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name[1]));
    readfile($file_name[1]);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hola Ivan... nada no hay caso. descarga 0 bytes..

Comment: Vale, lo siento, te recomendaría comprobar que la ruta $file_name[1] es correcta.